# Module 'ngStorage' is not available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

So, I'm new to angular and I'm building an app that saves data in the localStorage of my browser. I'm trying to use ngStorage for that but I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due      to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp.funcionarios due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngStorage due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngStorage' is not available! You either     misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure     that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/$injector/nomod?p0=ngStorage
at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2133:17
at ensure     (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2057:38)
at module (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2131:14)
at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4669:22
at forEach (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:325:20)
at loadModules (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4653:5)
at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4670:40
at forEach (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:325:20)
at loadModules     (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4653:5)
```

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/$injector/modulerr?

I have read a lot of foruns and I have worked on all the answers I could find but still no luck. Anyone can see something I'm missing?

This is my index scripts:

```
<script src="bower_components/ngstorage/ngStorage.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
<script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
<script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>
<script src="funcionarios/funcionarios.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

my app.js:

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.funcionarios', 'ngRoute', 'ngStorage' ])

.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider,     $routeProvider) {
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/funcionarios'});
}]);
```

and this is myApp.funcionarios:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.funcionarios', ['ngRoute', 'ngStorage'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/funcionarios', {
            templateUrl: 'funcionarios/funcionarios.html',
            controller: 'FuncionariosCtrl'
        });
    }])

      .controller('FuncionariosCtrl', ['$scope', '$localStorage',     '$sessionStorage', function( $scope, $localStorage, $sessionStorage ) {
```

Any help would be very much aprecciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just move your `ng-storage` script tag below angular. It depends on angular so it should be after that:

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ngstorage/ngStorage.js"></script>    
<script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
<script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
<script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>
<script src="funcionarios/funcionarios.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you Yaser. That fixed the problem!